# Durable subscription in Java (Qpid JMS) with Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am testing with pub/sub using Java and Qpid JMS 0.23.

I have created a topic in SB named "test.topic".

I can publish messages to the topic from test app but when trying to subscribe (dynamically creating subscription) it fails with exception:

> javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: The messaging entity 'mynamespace:topic:test.topic~15|DurableSubscriber2' could not be found. TrackingId:12ecc2a3-f8f3-42a3-8bd5-ad5d9823c367_B20, SystemTracker:mynamespace:topic:test.topic~15|DurableSubscriber2, Timestamp:8/8/2017 12:13:31 PM TrackingId:7e0d46404c8c45f39bffff2b77c7a140_G21, SystemTracker:gateway6, Timestamp:8/8/2017 12:13:31 PM [condition = amqp:not-found]

Some code:

```
env.put("topic.TOPIC", "test.topic");

Context context = new InitialContext(env);

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("SBCF");
Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("TOPIC");

connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("user", "secret");

subscriberSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

subscriber = subscriberSession.createDurableConsumer(topic, "DurableSubscriber2");
```

- Is it possible to create subscriptions on topic in SB from application?

If I create a static subscription named "sub1" on the topic it receives published messages. When retrieving I need to have the topic defined as:

```
test.topic/Subscriptions/sub1
```

i.e.

```
<<topic-name>>/Subscriptions/<<subscription-name>>
```

- Do I need to have some similar naming when dynamically subscribing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the section [`Unsupported features and restrictions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp#unsupported-features-and-restrictions) of the document `How to use the Java Message Service (JMS) API with Service Bus and AMQP 1.0` and focus on the option `Temporary destinations` as below.

> Temporary destinations, i.e., **TemporaryQueue**, **TemporaryTopic** are not currently supported, along with the **QueueRequestor** and **TopicRequestor** APIs that use them.

So I think dynamically create a subscription is not supported on Azure Service Bus.

Comment: Yes, I found out that you are correct that it is not supported with QPid/AMQP 1.0. Need to use this API if required: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java